# show and plan in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Can anyone tell how to change the variable name based on selection here default name is hide plan once i click the link the name should be show plan

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionLink("hide", "Hideplan"),
  shinyjs::hidden(DT::dataTableOutput("table")),DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))


server <- function(input,output){
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    iris
  })
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$hideshow, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id= "table")
    shinyjs::toggle(id= "table2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `modulo` `%%` check  for it, like so. So what is happening here:

-The `actionLink` is similar to an `actionButton` the events of which are incremented by 1 each time you press it, starting at 0, its all is doing

-We then shall check if the `input$hide` is divisible by 2 using the `modulo` operator, if it is then we change the button name to `Show plan` otherwise it will remain as `Hide plan`

-Starting at 0 = `Hide plan`, the First time you click = `Show plan`, button = 1, then click again, the count is now 2, hence it is divisible by 2 therefore we change the name to `Hide plan` again and so on

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionLink("hide", "Hide plan"),
    shinyjs::hidden(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
)


server <- function(input,output,session){
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        iris
    })
    output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        mtcars
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$hide, {
        if (input$hide %% 2 == 1) {
            txt <- "Show plan"
        } else {
            txt <- "Hide plan"
        }
        
        shinyjs::toggle(id= "table")
        shinyjs::toggle(id= "table2")
        updateActionButton(session, "hide", label = txt)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: i want to change my label name as show plan once i clicked the Hide plan action link @Pork Chop

Comment: but can you pls explain me the logic which you used inside the if condition

Comment: @Fariya, I put down some points of what is happening